# How to create an MSBuild target that depends on all C++ source files in a project?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I have a `Task`:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory">
    <Task>
     ...
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

And I have a target using that task:

```
  <Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="Midl">
    <MyTask .../>
  </Target>
```

How do I make `MyTask` depend on (and receive the paths to) all C++ source files in my project?

Comment: The ``ClCompile`` ItemGroup includes all the source cpp files in the standard vcxproj file.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Thanks for the pointer - would you mind giving some more details on how to use that to actually accomplish this? I'm by no means an MSBuild expert so it's not obvious to me.

Comment: Where are you defining the task exactly?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: The `UsingTask` element is under a `<Project>` element that's inside a `.props` file, which is referenced from my `.vcxproj` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual C++ projects, you are intended to add custom targets at the bottom of the file.

The **ClCompile** ItemGroup defines all the .c/.cpp files in the project. The **ClInclude** ItemGroup is all the headers.

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <Target Name="MyTarget" Outputs="%(ClCompile.Identity)" BeforeTargets="Midl">
    <Message Text="MyTarget %(ClCompile.Identity)" />
    <!-- MyTask can be invoked here -->
  </Target>
</Project>
```

See [MSBuild Targets - Target batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2022#target-batching)

Comment: Thanks a lot! A couple question to confirm: (1) Did you mean `Inputs` rather than `Outputs`? (2) Does `@` vs. `%` make any difference here? I tried `@` and it seemed to work too.

Comment: Generally MSBuild assumes that there is one output for every input, so the idiom is to use ``Outputs``. The ``%`` symbol is for metadata, while ``@`` indicates item lists. It basically depends on how your task is written. If you use ``@(ClCompile)`` then the whole item group is passed to **MyTask**. If you use ``%(ClCompile.Identity)`` then your MyTask is invoked once per item in the ClCompile ItemGroup.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But if I write `Outputs="%(ClCompile.Identity)"` wouldn't that mean the `.cpp` file is an *output*, though? Or if not - then how would MSBuild know what the name of the output file is, given that the `.cpp` file is an input? Also sorry, one more question - why is there a need for `BeforeTargets="Midl"` if the inputs are already explicitly specified? Shouldn't the target be able to run any time its inputs are ready?

Comment: I don't know what you are outputting here, but you can generate whatever you want in the targets.  The **BeforeTargets** and **AfterTargets** clauses are to give you control over *when* things are executed in a VCXPROJ. Targets are NOT executed in MSBuild just because they are declared. They have to be invoked somehow. Usually through ``<Project DefaultTargets="...">`` statements in standalone MSBuild, but this is controlled in a VCXPROJ by things inside the Microsoft MSBuild rules so you need to use the hook attributes.